# How do I know if a sound is finished playing in android?

Tags: android, soundpool

How do I know if a sound has finished playing?

I want to play 2 sounds but I want one sound to play and then wait until the 1st sound is done before the 2nd starts.

Also, if I wanted to do something else when the sound is finished like show he next view in a view flipper, could I do that?

Right now I'm using SoundPool to play my sounds.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class and an OnCompletionListener

Comment: Is there not a way to do this with SoundPool?  I need the low-latency of SoundPool.

Comment: Agree with Dahlgren MediaPlayer is the way to go.  You can pre-laod the sound with prepare(), then start() when you are ready to get a low latency playback.

Comment: Can I load up 20+ sounds using MediaPlayer, Or do I have to have 20+ instances of MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea... get ogg/wav sound play time length and use your own SoundObject class with timer member. 
Update it in some update function. 
If timer > maxtime + threshold, flag it as finished.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is too late to reply. But i used isPlaying() API from mediaplayer to wait for first song to complete.

```
while(mediaPlyaer.isPlaying()){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is to create an animation sequence that contains an image, a sound, and a delay.  I can then queue these up so I can have a image shown, and sound accompany it, and then switch to another image.  I do this with a SoundPlayer and a custom view (not a view flipper, though you probably could)

The trick is that you can't simply pause the thread for the delay, you'll need to use a handler to send yourself a message to update the UI in the future.

Here is the Handler

```
handler = new Handler() {

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.os.Handler#handleMessage(android.os.Message)
             */
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == NEXT_ITEM_MSG) {
                    showNext();
                }
                else if (msg.what == SEQUENCE_COMPLETE_MSG) {
                    // notify the listener
                    if (animationCompleteListener != null) {
                        animationCompleteListener.onAnimationComplete();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

The showNext() method simply grabs the next item in the sequence, updates the image view, plays the sound, and then schedules a message for the handler to call showNext after the sequence.

```
private void showNext() {
        if (mRunning) {
            // Get the first item
            AnimatedSequenceItem item = currentSequence.getNextSequenceItem();
            if (item == null) {
                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(SEQUENCE_COMPLETE_MSG);
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                return;
            }
            // Show the first image
            showImage(item.getImageResId());
            // Play the sound
            int iSoundResId = item.getSoundResId();
            if (iSoundResId != -1) {
                playSound(iSoundResId);
            }

            // schedule a message to advance to next item after duration
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(NEXT_ITEM_MSG);
            handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, item.getDuration());
        }
    }
```

Of course all of this does require you to determine and hardcode the delays, but in my experience you need to do that for a game anyway.  I had many cases where I wanted the delay to be longer than the sound.  Here's the code that actually queues up items.

```
battleSequence.addSequenceItem(R.drawable.brigands, 
                   R.raw.beep, 
                   2000);
battleSequence.addSequenceItem(R.drawable.black,
                               winning ? R.raw.enemy_hit : R.raw.player_hit, 
                               1500);
```

With this approach I can have all sorts of logic to add animation items, change durations, loop animations, etc...  It just took some fine tuning to get the delays right.

Hope this helps.