# How to know when the sound finished playing using soundPool

Tags: android, soundpool

I am using `sound pool` to play a short sound files in `android`, but I want to play the sounds at for example, If I clicked a button to play a sound and clicked the button again, I don't want to play the sound as long as it is already playing . how ?

Comment: Do you know the duration of the sound files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should use a MediaPlayer Class instead of soundpool to accomplish this result, in combination with an OnClickListener.

A simple StackOverflow search returns the following:

- [MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319838/how-do-i-know-if-a-sound-is-finished-playing-in-android)